# Subtleties in AdS$_2$/CFT$_1$

Tags: gravity, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft

I was looking at few papers on AdS$_2$/CFT$_1$. It seems to me that this is not as well studied as the higher dimensional dualities (e.g,  AdS$_3$/CFT$_2$ or AdS$_5$/CFT$_4$). Can someone summarize what the actual difficulties are. For example, I have some related questions in this setup.

1. How to define a CFT$_1$? Is it just quantum mechanics with conformal  invariance?
2. How to define central charge of CFT$_1$? What will be its physical meaning (like degrees of freedom, anomaly or Casimir energy)?
3. I came across the statement that AdS$_2$ is not stable by itself. One needs to have electric flux to make it stable. Why/how is it so? And if it is true then what is its analog in the dual CFT$_1$?

(If someone wishes to answer this, please feel free to discuss  other subtleties related to AdS$_2$/CFT$_1$ .)

Comment: Could you please give references to one or two of the papers you had looked at?

Comment: Well, here is one : https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9812073 
Summarizing this paper briefly will be a great answer to my question actually. :-)